# object == nil or nil == object to check whether an object is nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

While checking whether an object is nil, someone use 1:

```
if (object == nil) {
    //...
}
```

someone use 2:

```
if (nil == object) {
    //...
}
```

Any difference between 1 and 2? Which one is better?

Comment: there is no difference between both..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is mainly that if you mistakingly forget a `=` e.g like this

```
 (nil = myObject)
```

you will get an error cause you can't assign a value to nil. So it is some kind of faile-safe.

Answer (score 4):

The use of `nil == object` is actually an idiom to prevent the unlucky case where you miss a `=` in your expression. Example, you want to write:

```
if (object == nil)
```

but write:

```
if (object = nil) {
```

this is a typical error and one that is very difficult to track down, since the assignment has also a value as an expression and thus the condition will evaluate to false (no error), but you will also have wiped out your object...

On the other hand, writing

```
if (nil == object)
```

you ensure that that kind of error will be detected by the compiler since

```
if (nil = object)
```

is not a regular assignment.

Actually, modern compilers (default settings) will provide a warning for the kind of "unintended" assignment, ie:

```
if (object = nil) {
```

will raise a warning; but still this can be tricky.

Answer (score 4):

As others pointed out, they are equivalent. There is also another way to do it:

```
if (!object) {
    // object is nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason some developers prefer "[Yoda conditionals](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions)" is that it's less likely to inadvertently write `if (object = nil)` (note the assignment).

This is not an issue any more since compilers warn when assigning in a conditional expression without extra parentheses.

Since Yoda conditionals are less readable they should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent. Back in the days it was common to write `if (CONST == variable)` to reduce the risk of accidental assignment. E.g. `if (variable = CONST)` would assign a constant to the variable and the if-statement would evaluate as true or false depending on the value of the constant, not the variable.

Nowadays, IDEs and compilers will usually be smart enough to issue a warning on such lines. And many people prefer the first version due to readability. But really it's a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, only in readability I prefer the first one, while some other developers may prefer the other.

Its just a coding style issue, it has no technical difference at all.

Some may say that the second is better, since it is more explicit, the `nil` comes first so its easier to note that we are testing for `nil`, but again it depends on the developer taste.

Answer (score 1):

best practice when using the comparison operator == is to put the constant on the left of the operand.  in this way it is impossible to accidentally mistype the assignment operator instead of the comparison.

example:

( iVarOne == 1 )

is functionally equal to

( 1 == iVarOne)

but

( iVarOne = 1 )

is much different than

( 1 = iVarOne )

this best practice works around the fact that compilers do not complain when you mistype an assignment for a comparison operator...

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference at all. It's all about readability. If you want to write a clean code, you should take care of this.

If you place the "Object" to the right of the evaluation, it becomes less apparent what are you really doing.

Answer (score -3):

It is not NIL, it is NULL.
They are one and the same. The == operator is a comparison operator. As a general trend, we use (object==NULL)

Comment: In Objective-C (as the question is tagged), it is `nil` in this case.